# Dynamic range creation

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a variable reference for a dynamic range. My code is below. 
All seems working fine besides the last line  `Range(startcells, Lastrow).Select`, which returns an error of "method of range and object required". Any idea why?

I think there is a problem on how I define the lastrow... because if I select the startcells alone it works.

```
Sub colvar()

  ' select the entire column
   Dim lcol As Integer
   lcol = Sheets("A").Range("B1").Value
   Sheets("B").Activate

   Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long, startcells As Range
   Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, lcol).End(xlUp).Row
   i = 6
   Set startcells = Cells(i, lcol)

   'startcells.Select
    Range(startcells, Lastrow).Select


 End Sub
```

Comment: `LastRow` is a `Long`, not a `Range`. You can't select `7` or `234` or `339232` for example. Perhaps you are looking to use `Cells(LastRow, lcol)`?

Comment: Hi @BigBen, let me try!

Comment: It works great! many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an agrument is missing on your code. Here is the code for create a new table that contains all filled cells in the current sheet

```
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim NewTableRange As Range

'1st you need to find your last row & column
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).row

   LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(StartCell.row, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'2nd you set the need table range   
    Set NewTableRange = ActiveSheet.Range(StartCell, ActiveSheet.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
```